# how to find which field is giving error in query

Tags: sybase

How to find which field is giving error in query:

> com.abc.fast.common.db.exception.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{call p_proc_u(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; [ErrorCode: 257; SQLState: 42000; Message: Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'NUMERIC' is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. (DataSource: 1, Type: SYBASE)]; nested exception is com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'NUMERIC' is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that a numeric value is getting enclosed in quotes, or a character value is missing quotes.

Double check your code to make sure values are being properly passed into the database.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but that appears to be a valid datatype declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing this using Spring's Stored Procedure template, make sure the order of your 'declareParameter' is in the same order as the parameter list as specified in the destination stored procedure.

Given a stored proc that looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ac_createStoredProc

(
    @pFirst_name  VARCHAR(100),
    @pLast_name   VARCHAR(100)  = NULL,
    @pAge         NUMERIC(2,0) = NULL
```

declare your parameters like this

```
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(FIRST_NAME, Types.VARCHAR));
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(LAST_NAME,  Types.VARCHAR));
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(AGE,        Types.NUMERIC));
```

and it will be fine.  Declare your parameters like this:

```
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(AGE,        Types.NUMERIC));
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(FIRST_NAME, Types.VARCHAR));
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(LAST_NAME,  Types.VARCHAR));
```

Well, basically, just don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the variable values it finally used to call stored proc. This can be acheived by seting jdbctemplate logger to DEBUG mode. For example if you are using Spring jdbctempate then you can set property log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core to DEBUG. This can be done in log4j.properties or logback.xml.